# Animations disabled by bootstrap because using prefers-reduced-motion: reduce

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have noticed that the bootstrap modal animations don't make any animation when open or close, After check the bootstrap CSS file I found that the problem from `prefers-reduced-motion: reduce` i don't need my sites to support this media.

What can I do to makes the animations back again to my site?

The problem happens in FireFox and not happen in Google Chrome!!

Answer (score 10):

This is exactly how Bootstrap *should* work given the user's state preference of not seeing animations.

To override this behavior would be to deviate from the user's expectations and desires and would not be appropriate.

It's an accessibility issue. For someone with severe motion sickness, vertigo, or a handful of other physical or cognitive issues, animations can be really disorienting.

In other words, it doesn't matter what you want. Don't try to "fix" this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using sass to compile your files you can set `$enable-prefers-reduced-motion-media-query` to `false` (default `true`) to stop the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To get animations back to your site, add the code from [this link](https://gist.github.com/robsonsanches/33c6c1bf4dd5cf3c259009775883d1c0) to your project

This will force Bootstrap transitions to work again.

Comment: Thank you for this Rob!

Comment: The link is broken :-/

Comment: @johanvs The link has been updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla have [published a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#User_preferences) of what triggers this behaviour under certain conditions

in my case it was a combination of using Firefox, Windows 10, and having **Ease of Access > Show Animations** turned off. turning it back on resolved this issue with Bootstrap Modals fading

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded bootstrap through npm or composer then you can set the sass variable `$enable-reduced-motion` to `false`.

// for `npm`

The variable `$enable-reduced-motion` is located in `"your-project-folder/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss"` file.

//for `composer`

The variable `$enable-reduced-motion` is located in "`your-project-folder/vendor/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss"` file.

Comment: How to do it without changing node_moules file?

Comment: Well, you can write your own transitions on the element you want to animate. There is not a way that I know of that will do without changing $enable-reduced-motion to false.